# np.transpose() and np.reshape() combination gives different results in pure numpy and in numba

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numba

The following code produces different outputs:

```
import numpy as np

from numba import njit


@njit
def resh_numba(a):
    res = a.transpose(1, 0, 2)
    res = res.copy().reshape(2, 6)
    return res

x = np.arange(12).reshape(2, 2, 3)

print("numpy")
x_numpy = x.transpose(1, 0, 2).reshape(2, 6)
print(x_numpy)

print("numba:")
x_numba = resh_numba(x)
print(x_numba)
```

Output:

```
numpy
[[ 0  1  2  6  7  8]
 [ 3  4  5  9 10 11]]
numba:
[[ 0  4  8  2  6 10]
 [ 1  5  9  3  7 11]]
```

What is the reason for this? I'm suspecting some `order='C'` vs `order='F'` happening somewhere, but I expected both numpy and numba to use `order='C'` by default everywhere.

Comment: With this transpose `order` doesn't make much sense.   The transpose is achieved by changing the strides to (24,48,8).  To do the reshape `numpy` does a copy (or copy and ravel).   I can't figure out what the `numba` is doing.  It almost looks it's `reshape(4,3)` followed by taking diagonals.  I don't expect `numba` to be much faster even if it got it right.

Comment: @hpaulj I use numba to optimize other operations in my code, which I removed when creating the MCVE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is to a bug due (at least) to the np.ndarray.copy implementation, I opened an issue here: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/3557